# Why am I getting Segmentation fault(core dumped) in Bounded buffer problem?

Tags: c, operating-system, pthreads, semaphore

The following code is a simple implementation of the Producer/Consumer problem also called the Bounded Buffer Problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>

//buffer keeps track of the number of items produced and consumed
int buffer = 0;

pthread_mutex_t lock;

// full and empty are used to keep track of the spaces empty and filled by the items
sem_t full,empty;

void *producer()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    sem_wait(&empty);

    buffer++;
    printf("Producer produced %d \n",buffer);

    sem_post(&full);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
void *consumer()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    sem_wait(&full);

    printf("Consumer consumes %d \n",buffer);
    buffer--;

    sem_post(&empty);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}


int main()
{
    pthread_t T1;

    pthread_mutex_init(&lock,NULL);

    sem_init(&empty,0,10);
    sem_init(&full,0,0);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&T1,NULL,producer(),NULL);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&T1,NULL,consumer(),NULL);
    }

    pthread_join(T1,NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
    sem_destroy(&empty);
    sem_destroy(&full);
    return 0;

}
```

I am not getting complete output most of the times,
e.g: The consumer thread does not consume all the items and gets stuck at segmentation fault and also the producer thread does not create all the items sometimes.(Also I have fixed the size of buffer to not increase more than 10).
Can someone explain to me, why do I keep getting Segmentation Fault at the end, and a way to fix it?

Comment: It's borken anyway.  Waits inside a mutex lock are a deadlock magnet:(  Move the mutex operations inside the semaphore posts/waits.  Only the buffer ++/-- needs protection.

Comment: You are waiting for only one of the 20 P/C threads to terminate:(

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks mate. This time I put only the buffer count inside the mutex lock but it still seems to give me the same error. Any thoughts?
``

Comment: The printf's should be outside the mutex too.  Comment out the join and wait on stdin with a getchar() or scanf() to prevent the 'main' thread from exiting/terminating early.

Answer (score 1):

One major error:

> ```
>         pthread_create(&T1,NULL,producer(),NULL);
> …
>         pthread_create(&T1,NULL,consumer(),NULL);
> ```

You must pass the (addresses of the) functions `producer` and `consumer`, not the results of the function calls, as you did.